Retrieving drive items from Teams Channel
I'm writing a simple application in WPF/C# to retrieve the Drive Items (files)
from a Teams Channel. Next after I can list the files, I want to manipulate them: read, write, delete.
At this moment I cannot retrieve the files using the methods below.
I have read lots of posts here and on Microsoft documentation, but
whenever I use async/await the app is going in a loop, and never execute. I'm saving the
information from sbChannelItems on my local drive as .txt to see the output and verify code execution.
The WPF app has an authentication method that works. There is a button that has
the below method.
Help greatly appreciated. Thank you!
// Button's event
private void ButtonAccessTeamsChannel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    GetDriveItemsAsynch();
}
// The method
StringBuilder sbChannelItems = new StringBuilder();
public async Task<Microsoft.Graph.Models.DriveItemCollectionResponse> GetDriveItemsAsynch()
{
    sbChannelItems.Clear();
    string refreshToken = "...";
    OnBehalfOfCredential onBehalfOfCredential = new OnBehalfOfCredential(
            tenantId: Tenant,
            clientId: ClientId,
            clientSecret: ClientSecret,
            userAssertion: refreshToken
            );

    GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(onBehalfOfCredential, scopes);
    var members = graphClient.Drives["driveId"].Items["root"].Children.GetAsync();
    sbChannelItems.AppendLine("Members: " + members.Result.Value.ToString());

    return await Task.Run(() => graphClient.Drives["driveId"].Items["root"].Children.GetAsync());
}

